# std::vector size?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, std, initializer-list

Program:

```
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int>::size_type size=3;
    std::vector<int> v{size};
}
```

when compiled with

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

generates error:

```
ppp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ppp.cpp:5:28: error: narrowing conversion of ‘size’ from ‘std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-fpermissive]
ppp.cpp:5:28: error: narrowing conversion of ‘size’ from ‘std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-fpermissive]
```

and on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/ it is written

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

I expected that constructor to be used.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but you don't need the `typename` in front of `std::vector<int>::size_type`: there is no dependent name here.

Comment: @Luc I removed it. It was here because the code fragment was taken from more complex context.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not calling the constructor that sets the vector to an initial size.

```
std::vector<int> v{size};
```

The above creates a `vector` containing a single `int` element with the value `size`. You're calling this constructor:

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The braced-initializer list gets deduced as an `std::initializer_list<size_type>` and then a narrowing conversion must be performed since the `vector` itself contains `int`s.

To set the initial size of the vector use:

```
std::vector<int> v(size);  // parentheses, not braces
```

---

Also, the `vector` constructor you've listed no longer exists, it was removed in C++11 and replaced by the following two constructors:

```
vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());

explicit vector( size_type count );
```

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) is a much better reference as compared to cplusplus.com.

Comment: I was convinced narrowing conversions weren't allowed, and §8.5.4 seems to confirm that. However, my GCC 4.8 snapshot seems to swallow that with a warning.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm surprised it does, a regression bug maybe? 4.7.2 [complains](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c3226ac09fda294963cae1fbe20dba14) as expected

Comment: @Prætorian So if I had chosen for `value_type` some other (not implicitly convertible to unsigned long) type like `enum A { a, b, c };` it would be fine?

Comment: @Predrag It's the other way around, if `value_type` were implicitly convertible to `size_type` **and** the conversion would preserve the original value, the compiler wouldn't have complained. But the result would still be different, because you wanted a vector that had `n` default initialized elements in it, instead you're getting one with a single element having the value `n` in it.

Comment: @Prætorian: Technically, he is correct; if he used a `value_type` that isn't implicitly convertible to the `size_type`, then he could pass the `size_type` field in an initailizer list, and since it couldn't convert it into `initializer_list<value_type>`, it would call the right one.